# Scheme : What is wrong with my code?

Tags: if-statement, lambda, scheme

This question might be so easy, but I spent some time on it and I could not figure out what the problem is. I am new to Scheme ;)
Okay, this is my code:

```
(define foo
        (lambda (x)
              ((if(equal? (car x) 4) "A" "B")
               (if(equal? (car (cdr x)) 3) "A" "B")
               (if(equal? (car(cdr (cdr x))) 5) "A" "B")
               )
               ))


(foo '(4 3 5))
```

I get the following error, when I run the code:

```
>  application: not a procedure;  expected a procedure that can be
> applied to arguments   given: "A"   arguments...:    "A"    "A"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix the error, simply do this:

```
(define foo
  (lambda (x)
    (if (equal? (car x) 4) "A" "B")
    (if (equal? (car (cdr x)) 3) "A" "B")
    (if (equal? (car (cdr (cdr x))) 5) "A" "B")))
```

The problem? that in your code there's an extra and erroneous pair of `()` surrounding the `if` expression, so Scheme thinks that `if` is returning a function (which is not). Remember, in Scheme this: `(f)` means: execute `f` as a function with no arguments.

Now that we found the syntax error, let's see what else is wrong with the code. For starters, if you write a sequence of expressions inside a procedure only the value of the *last* one is returned, so the first two `if`s are being completely ignored! After reading the comments I understand that you want to return `"AAA"` for the input `'(4 3 5)`, or `"ABA"` for input `'(4 6 5)`. The trick here is that we must use `string-append` to stick together all the strings:

```
(define foo
  (lambda (x)
    (string-append
     (if (equal? (car x) 4) "A" "B")
     (if (equal? (cadr x) 3) "A" "B")
     (if (equal? (caddr x) 5) "A" "B"))))
```

Now it works as expected:

```
(foo '(4 3 5))
=> "AAA"
(foo '(4 6 5))
=> "ABA"
```

Comment: @ScottHunter I'm getting to that part now

Comment: Thank you for your answer @ÓscarLópez; But actually the program I am trying to write is the one with input-output's like below:
input: '(4 3 5)  output: "A" "A" "A" (or "AAA")   ;    
input: '(4 6 5)  output: "B" "B" "B" (or "BBB")    
I want to check three different condition in the body of my program and return three different output for each condition.

Comment: @sara_123 you really, really should have said that from the beginning. :( I updated my answer, I believe now it's what you intended in the first place

Comment: @ÓscarLópez, sorry for the confusion.
Yes, I should have said it in the question. I just mentioned it in the first comment I sent.
Thank you so much for your useful answers :)

Answer (score 3):

Let me start off by saying, "Welcome to Scheme!"  Don't get frustrated and whatever you do, keep on
trying to understand the functional-programming way of doing things.
Your perseverance will pay off, and you will become a better programmer
for the effort, even when you go back to using Java.

Scheme is a good place to start learning functional programming.

I hope the following will help you to see how you might start to 
change your thinking, so here goes:

Here is a bit about why you got the weird error you saw.  If you
have:

```
(define foo
        (lambda (x)
              ((if(equal? (car x) 4) "A" "B")
               (if(equal? (car (cdr x)) 3) "A" "B")
               (if(equal? (car(cdr (cdr x))) 5) "A" "B")
               )
               ))
```

Then:

```
(foo '(4 3 5))
```

is equal to:

```
((if (equal? (car '(4 3 5)) 4) "A" "B"))
 (if (equal? (car (cdr '(4 3 5))) 3) "A" "B")
 (if (equal? (car (cdr (cdr '(4 3 5)))) 5) "A" "B"))
```

Because that is what you get when you replace every occurrence
of `x` with `(4 3 5)` in the body of the lambda-expression you wrote.

This next bit of reasoning is a bit of a shortcut, but notice that:
    `(car '(4 3 5))` = `4`
  AND
    `(car (cdr '(4 3 5)))` = `(car '(3 5))` = `3`
  AND
  `(car (cdr (cdr '(4 3 5))))` = `(car (cdr '(3 5)))` = `(car '(5))` = `5`

So, when we substitute equals for equals in the above expression,
we get:

```
((if (equal? 4 4) "A" "B")
 (if (equal? 3 3) "A" "B")
 (if (equal? 5 5) "A" "B"))
```

and this is the same as:

```
("A" "A" "A")
```

This is a peculiar Scheme expression, and the reason Scheme complains is 
because you're trying to invoke a function called `"A"` and apply it to
two arguments, `"A"` and `"A"`.

From the discussion above, it's pretty clear that you're trying to 
derive a new structure, based on the input.  So, what you need is
a function which derives the new structure, based on an examination
of the existing structure, and assembles a new one.  This is what
is returned by the function.

Scheme is a functional language, which means that it is very
expression-oriented.  In Scheme, the computer is turned into a kind of
mechanical expression-evaluator.  This is very different from
what we became used to in object-oriented languages (e.g., Java,
C#) because those languages are all about carefully controlling
changeable state.  In functional languages, it's all about
calculating the value of an expression.  (By the way, In a deep
and beautiful way, it just so happens that everything you can
do in the world of "mutable state programming" can be done in
the world of "mechanical evaluation of expressions."  There's a
deep and fundamental equivalence between the two, believe it or not.)

If you are trying to create a new list, based on tests of the individual
elements in list (4 3 5), then you need to write expressions which do
two separate things:  construct lists from smaller things, and examine 
the various elements of the list (in this case, 4, 3, and 5.)

```
(define foo
  (lambda (x)
    (cons (if (equal? (car x) 4) "A" "B")
      (cons (if (equal? (car (cdr x)) 3) "A" "B")
        (cons (if (equal? (car (cdr (cdr x))) 5) "A" "B") '() )))))
```

So, `(foo '(4 3 5))` results in `("A" "A" "A")`, which is a list of strings.
You eventually want to append them all together into a single string,
right?  So, there's already a function called `fold-right` which provides
a way to do this.  The `fold-right` function can use the string-append
function to accomplish this:

```
(fold-right string-append "" (foo '(4 3 5)))
```

which should provide an answer of "AAA".

```
(fold-right string-append "" (foo '(4 4 4)))
```

gives an answer of `"ABB"`

Using functions like `fold`, `fold-right`, etc, is a more of a functional
programming way to do these kinds of things.

Depending on the circumstances, you may want to use those folding functions
instead of writing the `foo` function in terms of the `string-append` function, as
Oscar Lopez did above.

Like I said earlier, you have to think about things very differently
when using a functional programming language, and get away from thinking
of programs as sequences of operations which change the internal state
of the computer's memory.  You have to start thinking in terms of the
computer as a powerful expression evaluation machine instead.

I hope this helps, and is an encouragement to you to keep working at learning Scheme.

Comment: You're welcome.  Scheme's a great place to learn about and experiment with expression-oriented thinking, recursion, and how to using recursion to operate on recursively defined structures, like lists and computer programs.  And it's just awesome...

Sorry, I got a little carried away.  _The Little Lisper_ or _The Little Schemer_ are wonderful books that are really helpful.  After those, I recommend _Essentials of Programming Languages, 2nd Edition_, which is just awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Because the body of your lambda is wrapped in parentheses, the first `if` is being treated as a procedure, and when it tries to apply the results of the other `if`'s to it, you get the error you got.

If you are trying to return a list of the values of those 3 `if`'s, then you should use the `list` function.

Comment: It is just a simple program that I want to return "AAA" for the input '(4 3 5), or "ABA" for input '(4 6 5).

Comment: I was just trying to practice and learn more about Scheme that I came to this point that I can't have three if-statement inside the body of a procedure.
It is so easy to write such a program in other languages such as Java or C++. How can I do that in Scheme? How can I write a procedure that have this three if-statements and return three symbols of (A or B)?

Comment: @sara_123 : you can certainly use "begin" to sequence expressions just as you would in Java. Your question is really about something else, though. Take another look at how you'd write it in Java.